# What's wrong with this deletion call

Tags: java

Attached is a sample code, I am trying to **clear** old content of the list before filling it with new data but it doesn't seem to be working.
Let's say if in first call I got list of size 4 and in second call size of 6, then it's making the list grow to size of 10. What I want is only data from most recent call.

```
public class DemoClass
{
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();


    public void doSomething()
    {

      myList =  getMyList("params");
      System.out.println(myList.toString());

      //Results in ArrayList of size 3 = AAA, BBB, CCC 

    }


    public void doAnotherThing()
    {

      myList = getMyList("different params"); // Actual size returned is 4

      System.out.println(myList.toString());
      //Results in ArrayList of size 7 = AAA, AAA, BBB, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE 

    }

     public List<String> getMyList(String params)
     {
         //Some business Logic based on params

         myList.clear();
         myList = //code to populate the list

         return myList;
     }
}
```

Comment: We need some information about how you are using those methods? Where are you calling them from?

Comment: Why is `myList` a global variable if you're passing it with return anyway? Is it some sort of cache? Why clear it instead of just creating a new one and deleting the myList field entirely?

Comment: kept myList global because it's being used by some other methods as well.

Comment: @breakingBad Methods that do *not* call `getMyList` directly? And adding one extra argument `myList` to those methods is not feasible?

Comment: @lusicubal, it's actually someone's else code, too many other dependencies. There is no way to clear out this global list?

Comment: So... what does the debugger say about this? Look at what's actually happening in the code and see whether the list that's being cleared and repopulated and the one that you're printing out are really the same list. Also use it to doublecheck that things happen in the order you expect them to happen. Or that "some business logic" actually does what you think it does and isn't responsible for the duplicate entries in and of itself.

Comment: @millimoose, going to run it through debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getMyList() looks fine on its, except for the fact that myList is global, as others have mentioned. myList.clear() is indeed the correct way to clear a list. Try creating a new list inside getMyList() and see if the problem persists; with your current architecture you have to be absolutely certain that everything in this class that deals with myList gets called on the same thread.

With the code you have now it is very difficult to isolate where your problem is occurring -- perhaps it is in the logic for getMyList()? Perhaps another method jumps in and modifies myList? Impossible to know. If getMyList() returns a completely new list, which you can then assign to myList (in doAnotherThing(), for example) later, then you will at least be able to print the different lists at various points to see where the error is.

Comment: Thanks Logan, going to try new List creation. Will post back soon.